# Add column for txt file

Tags: batch-file

I want to add a column on a txt file with the date (which I retrieve via the filename) in batch file. Currently, I add for each end of line the name but it takes a long time. Is it possible to do more quickly?

The name file looks like: `MVSSYSA.PCEAS910.20181205033230`

```
@echo off
set Source=U:\Help
REM For all txt files
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /B /a-d "%Source%\*.txt"') DO (
   ECHO Adding %%G
   ECHO. >> %%G.txt

   REM I take the third word
   for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%f in ("%%~nG") do (
        set NewFileName=%%f
        REM For each line I add the date                               
           for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%Source%\%%~G") do (
                Echo %%a %1 %%f >> %%G.txt 
           )
    )
)
```

Comment: You are aware that your files end up with a doubled extension `.txt.txt` with that code? Also you are appending the cmd line arg `%1` to each line. You'll IMO need a different script/programming language to speed things up.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to remove the part with "echo .>>%%G.txt".I am a new programmer.. I done this code with the fusion of different code from forums.I'm forced to code in bat. Could you please help me to improve it ?

Comment: A text file doesn't have columns, just text. The text may possibly be separated by spaces, tabs, commas, semicolons or pipes. It would help potential responders were you to provide an example of the content and structure of the input text files, with an example of what you intend the resultant file to look like. Also you state that your file is named with the following structure, `MVSSYSA.PCEAS910.20181205033230`, but surely it would be named more like, `MVSSYSA.PCEAS910.20181205033230.txt`. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54076187/edit) to clarify matters.

Comment: As the question is off-topic here, as your code is working please remove it. Visit [help/on-topic] to learn what topics are allowed here.

Comment: It will take long to run as you are using 3 for loops for each file found. Also, you are adding double extensions as you are writing back to the original token `%%G.txt` which is the full filename but again with `.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It's the redirection `>>` which makes it slow - especially with big files. `>>` opens the file for writing, searches the end of text to be able to append, writes the new line and closes the file again. It does that for every single line, which takes time.

Better just do a single write operation. So instead of

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,1000) do echo %%a>>file.txt
```

which opens/writes/closes the file a thousand times, better do

```
(for /l %%a in (1,1,1000) do echo %%a)>file.txt
```

which redirects the whole output of the `for` loop to the file in a single open/write/close operation, which is a lot faster.

Applied to your code, it should look something like:

```
@echo off
set Source=U:\Help
REM For all txt files
FOR %%G IN ("%Source%\*.txt") DO (
   ECHO Adding %%G
   > %%G.txt (
     REM I take the third word
     for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%f in ("%%~nG") do (
        set NewFileName=%%f
        REM For each line I add the date                               
           for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%Source%\%%~G") do (
              Echo %%a %1 %%f 
           )
     )
   )
)
```

(Note: I didn't check your "payload" code, but I guess, there are a few issues as noted in the comments to your question)

Comment: Thanks for your help Stephan! I will try and I will come back to you .

Comment: prepare for disappointment. It will be fast*er*, but not *fast* `:)`

Comment: It's better than before :) . I have to do it for 20 files (a 1000Ko file). Do you think it is possible to change the code in order to modify the files in parallel?

Comment: You could use the `start` command to create a separate process for each file. A major redesign would be necessary, maybe even splitting into two batch files. But yes, this would work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I use the command start in my case?

Comment: I done 2 batch files : 

1)
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Source=U:\Help

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /B /a-d "%Source%\*.txt"') DO (
                     for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%f in ("%%~nG") do (
                               set NewFileName=%%f
          start "  Work.bat "%%G"
    )
)

2)  (Work.bat)

  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%Source%\%%~G") do (
                                               Echo %%a %1 %%f 
                               ) >> %%G

But I got error message, "The system don't find a file U:\Help\%~G"

Comment: please ask a new question. As you surely have noticed, code is nearly unreadable in comments. The errormessage is because `%%G` isn't valid outside it's `for` loop.

Comment: Before asking for help here, I tried using the start command but I did not succeed. As I said before, I am a new programmer. So, if I understand correctly, we put the part of the code that writes the date in another bat file.So how do I give it the name of the file?